# Using a pgfplots-style legend in a plain-old tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend

I am using a plain-old `tikzpicture` to produce a pie-chart-like plot. Now, all other plots in my paper are handled using `pgfplots` (which doesn't do pie charts) and have their legend typeset by `pgfplots`.

It would thus be great if it were possible to create, re-using as many keys like `/pgfplots/area legend` as possible, to create a pgfplots-style legend in TiKZ. Has anyone done anything like this before?

Comment: Would you mind uploading an example of how you create your pie charts?

Comment: I don't use any special package for that; just plain-old `tikzpicture` `\filldraw` and `arc` paths. (No package could easily do what I wanted to out of the box: a pie chart within a ring chart; sort of like a pie with a crust.)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Pgfplots has a couple of helper methods which do the job - and these methods are mostly independent of any axis. The only required things are the text labels and the styles for the individual images.

Here is a short draft which might do what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

% argument #1: any options
\newenvironment{customlegend}[1][]{%
    \begingroup
    % inits/clears the lists (which might be populated from previous
    % axes):
    \csname pgfplots@init@cleared@structures\endcsname
    \pgfplotsset{#1}%
}{%
    % draws the legend:
    \csname pgfplots@createlegend\endcsname
    \endgroup
}%

% makes \addlegendimage available (typically only available within an
% axis environment):
\def\addlegendimage{\csname pgfplots@addlegendimage\endcsname}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{customlegend}[legend entries={$a$,$e^x$,C,$d$}]
    \addlegendimage{red,fill=black!50!red,area legend}
    \addlegendimage{red,fill=black!50!red,sharp plot}
    \addlegendimage{red,fill=black!50!red,mark=*,sharp plot}
    \addlegendimage{red,fill=black!50!red,ybar,ybar legend}
    \end{customlegend}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The different `\addlegendimage` styles are a little bit ... inconsistent, but I wanted to experiment if they work. I guess that `mesh legend` might produce problems, so stick to the simpler ones...

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm.

Comment: This is really nice. I just don't know how I position the legend in the tikzpicture at the right spot. Tried to put it into a node, but got an error. Is there a general way to position something?

Comment: @Jana it is placed using the legend keys, i.e. add `legend style={at={(0.5,0.5)},anchor=center}` to the option list. Perhaps you can also omit the outer `legend style` and write `at=...` immediately.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this positioning using `legend style={at={(0.5,0.5)},anchor=center}` is to position the legend as if it was inside an axis environment. How should be done in order to position the legend using global coordinates of the tikz? Lets say that the legend should be a node positioned at (100,100)

Comment: `at={(100,100)}` should work.

Comment: How can I adapt `\addlegendimage{red,fill=black!50!red,mark=*,sharp plot}` to get a dotted line?

Comment: `\addlegendimage{red,fill=black!50!red,dashed,mark=*,sharp plot}` apparently.

Comment: How to arrange the legend keys horizontally instead of vertically?

Comment: oh, `legend columns=-1`. wow, can just use all the standard legend styles, great! :) Thank you :)

Comment: This seems to not work with `tikzexternalize` for some reason

Answer (score 8):

And here is how to put a non-pgfplots style legend into pgfplots.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=10,ymin=-5,ymax=5,name=border]
\end{axis}

\node[draw=black,thick,rounded corners=2pt,below left=2mm] at (border.north east) {%
\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{ }l@{}}
 \raisebox{2pt}{\tikz{\draw[black] (0,0) -- (5mm,0);}}&black\\
 \raisebox{2pt}{\tikz{\draw[red] (0,0) -- (5mm,0);}}&red\\
 \raisebox{2pt}{\tikz{\draw[green] (0,0) -- (5mm,0);}}&green\\
 \raisebox{2pt}{\tikz{\draw[blue] (0,0) -- (5mm,0);}}&blue
\end{tabular}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: plot with legend]

Comment: Instead of a `\fbox{}` I would use the tikz-node which contains the legend to draw the border. This way, you can easily specify line widths, colors and shapes. Just omit the `\fbox{PRESERVE THE CONTENT}` and add `draw`, `rounded corners` or the like afer the `\node[below left=1mm`.

Comment: @PaulPaulsen - You obviously already know how to do it, but okay.

Comment: Yeah, but I myself learned a lot of things like this from comments onother questions, so I thought I would just post it here in case somebody is looking for that...