# Legend in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend

I am looking for a way to create a legend in a regular tikzpicture. I found this

[Using a pgfplots-style legend in a plain-old tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54794/using-a-pgfplots-style-legend-in-a-plain-old-tikzpicture)

but I don't know

- how to put the legend at the wanted position and
- how to add an entry with just a number instead of a symbol, like `'1  number of ...'`.

I don't need this. I just want to create easily a box where I have colored lines, colored circles/rectangles.. and colored numbers and the description next to.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you want to use pgfplots tools or TikZ? Do you want to place the legend automatically ? It's relatively simple too create  your personal legend with some nodes and where you want. Perhaps you can add the code to get your picture ...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here is a solution based on [Using a pgfplots-style legend in a plain-old tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54794/using-a-pgfplots-style-legend-in-a-plain-old-tikzpicture#54834). There are two examples: in the first one, the descriptions in the legend are centered, while in the second one, the descriptions are left aligned.

To define numbers in the legend, I added a key `number in legend`:

```
% definition to insert numbers
\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/number in legend/.style={%
        /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
            \node at (0.295,0){#1};
        },%
    },
}
```

> **Centered descriptions**

The example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shadings}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

% Code from Christian Feuersänger
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54794/using-a-pgfplots-style-legend-in-a-plain-old-tikzpicture#54834

% argument #1: any options
\newenvironment{customlegend}[1][]{%
    \begingroup
    % inits/clears the lists (which might be populated from previous
    % axes):
    \csname pgfplots@init@cleared@structures\endcsname
    \pgfplotsset{#1}%
}{%
    % draws the legend:
    \csname pgfplots@createlegend\endcsname
    \endgroup
}%

% makes \addlegendimage available (typically only available within an
% axis environment):
\def\addlegendimage{\csname pgfplots@addlegendimage\endcsname}

%%--------------------------------

% definition to insert numbers
\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/number in legend/.style={%
        /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
            \node at (0.295,-0.0225){#1};
        },%
    },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)--(10,0);
\draw(0,-0.2)--(0,0.2)node[above,red]{\small{0}};
\draw(10,-0.2)--(10,0.2)node[above,blue]{\small{1}};
%------------------%
\foreach \m[count=\mi] in {0.909090909,...,9.090909090}
\draw(\m,-0.1)--(\m,0.1) node[anchor=north](a\mi){};
\draw[dotted]($(a2)+(0,0.1)$)--($(a2)+(0,0.4)$);
\draw[dotted]($(a3)+(0,0.1)$)--($(a3)+(0,0.4)$);
\draw[stealth-stealth,red,opacity=0.4]($(a3)+(0,0.4)$)--($(a2)+(0,0.4)$)node[anchor=south west,xshift=0.23cm,black,opacity=1]{\small{$R$}};
%------------------%
\foreach \x/\xtext in {0.7/$u_1$,1.2/$u_2$,4.5/$u_3$,5.2/$u_4$,5.6/$u_5$,7.5/$u_6$}
\shade[ball color=blue]  (\x,0 ) circle (0.1cm) node[below=0.1cm]{\small{\xtext}};
%------------------%
% inf user
\shade[ball color=green]  (0,0 ) circle (0.1cm) node[below=0.1cm]{\small{$u_{inf}$}};

\begin{customlegend}[
legend entries={ % <= in the following there are the entries
$R$: infection radius,
$u_i$: users,
$u_{inf}$: initial infected user, 
social space max dimension,
social space min dimension,
example of rectangle
},
legend style={at={(4.5,3.5)},font=\footnotesize}] % <= to define position and font legend
% the following are the "images" and numbers in the legend
    \addlegendimage{stealth-stealth,red,opacity=0.4}
    \addlegendimage{mark=ball,draw=white}
    \addlegendimage{mark=ball,ball color=green,draw=white}
    \addlegendimage{number in legend=1,blue}
    \addlegendimage{number in legend=0,red}
    \addlegendimage{area legend,orange,fill=orange!20}
\end{customlegend}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

> **Left aligned descriptions**

The code is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shadings}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

% Code from Christian Feuersänger
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54794/using-a-pgfplots-style-legend-in-a-plain-old-tikzpicture#54834

% argument #1: any options
\newenvironment{customlegend}[1][]{%
    \begingroup
    % inits/clears the lists (which might be populated from previous
    % axes):
    \csname pgfplots@init@cleared@structures\endcsname
    \pgfplotsset{#1}%
}{%
    % draws the legend:
    \csname pgfplots@createlegend\endcsname
    \endgroup
}%

% makes \addlegendimage available (typically only available within an
% axis environment):
\def\addlegendimage{\csname pgfplots@addlegendimage\endcsname}

%%--------------------------------

% definition to insert numbers
\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/number in legend/.style={%
        /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
            \node at (0.125,-0.0225){#1}; % <= changed x value
        },%
    },
}
\pgfplotsset{
every legend to name picture/.style={west}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)--(10,0);
\draw(0,-0.2)--(0,0.2)node[above,red]{\small{0}};
\draw(10,-0.2)--(10,0.2)node[above,blue]{\small{1}};
%------------------%
\foreach \m[count=\mi] in {0.909090909,...,9.090909090}
\draw(\m,-0.1)--(\m,0.1) node[anchor=north](a\mi){};
\draw[dotted]($(a2)+(0,0.1)$)--($(a2)+(0,0.4)$);
\draw[dotted]($(a3)+(0,0.1)$)--($(a3)+(0,0.4)$);
\draw[stealth-stealth,red,opacity=0.4]($(a3)+(0,0.4)$)--($(a2)+(0,0.4)$)node[anchor=south west,xshift=0.23cm,black,opacity=1]{\small{$R$}};
%------------------%
\foreach \x/\xtext in {0.7/$u_1$,1.2/$u_2$,4.5/$u_3$,5.2/$u_4$,5.6/$u_5$,7.5/$u_6$}
\shade[ball color=blue]  (\x,0 ) circle (0.1cm) node[below=0.1cm]{\small{\xtext}};
%------------------%
% inf user
\shade[ball color=green]  (0,0 ) circle (0.1cm) node[below=0.1cm]{\small{$u_{inf}$}};

\begin{customlegend}[legend cell align=left, %<= to align cells
legend entries={ % <= in the following there are the entries
$R$: infection radius,
$u_i$: users,
$u_{inf}$: initial infected user, 
social space max dimension,
social space min dimension,
example of rectangle
},
legend style={at={(4.5,3.5)},font=\footnotesize}] % <= to define position and font legend
% the following are the "images" and numbers in the legend
    \addlegendimage{stealth-stealth,red,opacity=0.4}
    \addlegendimage{mark=ball,draw=white}
    \addlegendimage{mark=ball,ball color=green,draw=white}
    \addlegendimage{number in legend=1,blue}
    \addlegendimage{number in legend=0,red}
    \addlegendimage{area legend,orange,fill=orange!20}
\end{customlegend}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This is pretty much what I want. Thank you. Just one question: How do I change the color of the numbers? For example when I want a green 1 and a red 1 in the legend.

Comment: Very easily, you can say: `\addlegendimage{number in legend=1,green}` and `\addlegendimage{number in legend=1,red}`.

Comment: I updated my answer with this modification.

Comment: Awesome. Ok one more questions (sorry): Is it possible to align all the description texts?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Do you want descriptions to be left aligned?

Comment: Yes. I tried 
'legend style={at={(4.5,3.5)},font=\footnotesize, align=left}]'
but that didn't work.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much.

Comment: Is is possible to make the positioning on the legend automatically attached to the top right of the axis?  I have 100 plots of different sizes and don't want to do this by hand for each one.

Comment: If you just use pgfplots no needs of such stuff, but if you have plain tikzpictures then can for example place a node, say named `x`, at the top right of your axis then use `legend style={at={(x)}` or similar.

Comment: How to put the legend entries in a single line?

Comment: @hengxin: You can use the classic `legend columns=-1` that should be provided in the options of `customlegend` environment.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean `legend style = {at = {(4,3)}, legend columns = -1}`? I got an error `Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/legend columns' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it`. Any ideas?

Comment: @hengxin: No, I mean: `[legend cell align=left, legend columns=-1,legend entries={...`