# Using node shapes or self made tikzpicture as image in legend

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, nodes, legend

I am using the solutions of

[Using a pgfplots-style legend in a plain-old tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54794/using-a-pgfplots-style-legend-in-a-plain-old-tikzpicture)

and

[Legend in tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62262/legend-in-tikzpicture)

to create a legend in a tikzpicture.

In this legend I need a cylinder as image. I know that a node can be shaped as a cylinder. But I don't now how I can use this to create a legend image.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

% node shaped as cylinder
\node[shape=cylinder](c) at (0,0){};

% cylinder drawn myself
\draw(3,3)--(4,3);
\draw(3,4)--(4,4);
\draw(3,2.5) ellipse (0.1 and 0.5);
\draw(4,2.5) ellipse (0.1 and 0.5);

\begin{customlegend}[legend cell align=left,
legend entries={ cylinder},
legend style={at={(6,3)},font=\footnotesize}]
\addlegendimage{ ??????? }
\end{customlegend}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Please make sure that your examples are complete and compilable (so they have to start from `\documentclass`), especially in a case like this where quite a bit of special code and certain packages are required. Otherwise, those trying to help have to do the work of figuring out how to compile the example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the code that's used to draw the legend image using `legend image code/.code={ ...}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

% Code from Christian Feuersänger
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54794/using-a-pgfplots-style-legend-in-a-plain-old-tikzpicture#54834

% argument #1: any options
\newenvironment{customlegend}[1][]{%
    \begingroup
    % inits/clears the lists (which might be populated from previous
    % axes):
    \csname pgfplots@init@cleared@structures\endcsname
    \pgfplotsset{#1}%
}{%
    % draws the legend:
    \csname pgfplots@createlegend\endcsname
    \endgroup
}%

% makes \addlegendimage available (typically only available within an
% axis environment):
\def\addlegendimage{\csname pgfplots@addlegendimage\endcsname}

%%--------------------------------

% definition to insert numbers
\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/number in legend/.style={%
        /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
            \node at (0.295,-0.0225){#1};
        },%
    },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% node shaped as cylinder
\node[shape=cylinder](c) at (0,0){};

% cylinder drawn myself
\draw(3,3)--(4,3);
\draw(3,4)--(4,4);
\draw(3,4) arc [x radius=0.1, y radius=0.5, start angle=90, end angle=270];
\draw(4,3.5) ellipse (0.1 and 0.5);

\begin{customlegend}[legend cell align=left,
legend entries={ cylinder},
legend style={at={(6,3)},font=\footnotesize}]
\addlegendimage{legend image code/.code={\node [draw, cylinder, minimum size=1em] {};}}
\end{customlegend}

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Jake's answer is perfect but if someone wants to add legend only with tikz, it's easy to take another way.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,fit}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\fill[orange!30] (4,0) arc [x radius=0.1, y radius=0.5, start angle=-90, end angle=90] 
             --  (3,1) arc [x radius=0.1, y radius=0.5, start angle=90, end angle=270]
             -- cycle ;                       
\draw[orange]   (4,0)  arc [x radius=0.1, y radius=0.5, start angle=-90, end angle=90] 
                       arc [x radius=0.1, y radius=0.5, start angle=90,  end angle=270]
            -- (3,0)   arc [x radius=0.1, y radius=0.5, start angle=270, end angle=90]
            -- (4,1) ;  

 \node[draw=orange,fill=orange!30,shape=cylinder,
       minimum width=1mm,minimum height=1cm,anchor=east](c) at (8,4){};  
 \node[anchor=west](ct) at (8,4){legend 1}; 
 \node[draw,fit=(ct)(c)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]