# Two columns in legend in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend

I know how to create a legend in a pgfplots plot.
See

[Legend in tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62262/legend-in-tikzpicture)

and

[Using a pgfplots-style legend in a plain-old tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54794/using-a-pgfplots-style-legend-in-a-plain-old-tikzpicture).

But I do not know how I can create a legend with two columns.

Comment: Have you tried using `\multicols` environment inside your legend code?

Comment: No, because I actually don't understand the code of the definition of the legend environment.

Comment: Try to enclose your `\addlegendimage`s in a `\multicols` environment like `\begin{multicols}{2} \addlegendimage \addlegendimage \addlegendimage \end{multicols}`

Comment: I can not get it to compile.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Simply set the key `legend columns=2`.

Depending on what you need, you might also be interested in `transpose legend` and/or `reverse legend`.

***EDIT:***

in order to customize the legend's appearance, you can use `legend style={<option list>}` where `<option list>` can be any option which applies to a PGF `\matrix`. All these options can be found in the PGF manual. The one which is necessary here is the `column sep` key. We have to restrict it to the second column (unless we also want to customize the column separation between images and text).

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        legend columns=2, 
        legend style={
                    % the /tikz/ prefix is necessary here...
                    % otherwise, it might end-up with `/pgfplots/column 2`
                    % which is not what we want. compare pgfmanual.pdf
            /tikz/column 2/.style={
                column sep=5pt,
            },
        },
    ]
        \addplot {x};
        \addlegendentry{$x$}
        \addplot {x+4};
        \addlegendentry{$x$+4}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to increase the space between the columns? Now the image of the 2nd column starts without space directly after the description of the item in the first column.

Comment: See my edit. It might better to add a further question in the future (will simplify searches for the follow-up question).

Answer (score 3):

This is a very old question but in case anyone else stumbles upon this I find it far easier to just add whitespace directly into the labels in question using "~".

Like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        legend columns=2
    ]
        \addplot {x};
        \addlegendentry{$x$~~~~~~}
        \addplot {x+4};
        \addlegendentry{$x$+4~~~~~~~}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```