# How to manually draw horizontal legend and place it correctly in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend

This is my tikz code to draw some plots.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,subfig}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subfloat[Iteration Domain for a Tile]{
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (3.8,3.8);
      \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \subfloat[Convex Bounding Boxes]{
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (3.8,3.8);
      \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \subfloat[Disjoint Bounding Boxes]{
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (3.8,3.8);
      \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \caption{Bounding boxes for disjoint union of data regions}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

And this is the output:

[image]

I want to draw something like this:

[image]

How do I do it?

There are mainly two things:

1. I want to put legend at the top.
2. I want to put some description for (a) and some description for both (b) and (c) as shown in above  figure.

Comment: Related/duplicates: [Legend in tikzpicture](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62262/13304) and [Using a pgfplots-style legend in a plain-old tikzpicture](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54794/13304).

Comment: Please change your LWE (Large Working Example) to a [MWE (Minimal Working Example)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). It will help answerers a lot more. Kind regards

Comment: I have tried and minimized the code.

Comment: Great, however, still your problem seems to be about placement of text above your figures, hence for this you do not need any other things a MWE for your figures could equally be: `\begin{tikzpicture}\draw (0,0) rectangle (4,4);\end{tikzpicture}`. By using that MWE you can still remove _many_ preamble lines (and also, `listings` is not used, so that should also be removed).

Comment: Please see how I would have done your MWE. It doesn't get any (it could, but...) shorter than this. Remember that this will help clarify your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Placing the legend on top can be done using the `pgfplots` package, but the shared title for (b) and (c) is a little hackish (i.e., positioning is manual). I was able to come up with the following.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,subfig}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=5cm,compat=newest,every axis legend/.append style={at={(0.5,1.35)}, anchor=south}}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subfloat[Iteration Domain for a Tile]{
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[title=Title]
        \addplot {x};
        \addlegendentry{Legend a}
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \subfloat[Convex Bounding Boxes]{
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        title style={at={(1.17,1)},overlay},
        title=Shared title
        ]
        \addplot [color=red,mark=o]{x^2};
        \addlegendentry{Legend b}
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \subfloat[Disjoint Bounding Boxes]{
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
        \addplot[color=black,mark=+] {x^3};
        \addlegendentry{Legend c}
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \caption{Bounding boxes for disjoint union of data regions}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]