# Matlab2tikz adds extra legend entries

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, matlab2tikz

The legend from a boxplot figure is not being created properly.

I get this:
[image]

Instead of thiS:
[image]
But really only need 2 legend entries. Any Ideas why all the objects in this plot are being given legend entries when in Matlab there are only 2 `light blue=4ACH` and `dark blue=6ACH`.

How do I make the two blue boxes using tikz code? `\addlegendentry` doesn't work because the boxplots are not plot items but filled objects defined by tables of coordinates

MVE

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subfig}
%\usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode} %matlab to latex s
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
 \pgfplotsset{compat=newest} 
 \pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\begin{document}

\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.6,0.8,1}
\definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=4.52083333333333in,
height=3.565625in,
scale only axis,
xmin=0.5, xmax=1.5,
xtick={1},
xticklabels={Direct Care,Housekeeping,Mealtimes,Medication Round,Miscellaneous,Personal Care},
ymin=-10, ymax=100,
ytick={0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100},
ylabel={Normalised cfu (Y) values},
legend style={draw=black,fill=white,legend cell align=left}
]

\addplot [
color=black,
solid
]
table{
0.755 0
0.895 0
};
\addlegendentry{4 ACH};

\addplot [
color=black,
solid
]
table{
0.755 0
0.895 0
};
\addlegendentry{4 ACH};

\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
line width=1.0pt
]
table{
0.685 0
0.965 0
};
\addlegendentry{4 ACH};

\addplot [
color=blue,
only marks,
mark=*,
mark options={solid,fill=mycolor1,draw=black}
]
table{
0.825 10.0567798116818
};
\addlegendentry{200 ACH};
\addplot [
color=black,
dotted
]
table{
0.825 0
0.825 0
};
\addlegendentry{4 ACH};
\addplot [
color=black,
solid
]
table{
0.755 0
0.895 0
};
\addlegendentry{4 ACH};

\addplot [
color=black,
solid
]
table{
0.755 0
0.895 0
};
\addlegendentry{4 ACH};

\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
line width=1.0pt
]
table{
0.685 0
0.965 0
};
\addlegendentry{4 ACH};

\addplot [
color=blue,
only marks,
mark=*,
mark options={solid,fill=mycolor1,draw=black}
]
table{
0.825 10.0567798116818
};
\addlegendentry{4 ACH};

\addlegendentry{6 ACH};

\addplot [
color=black,
dotted
]
table{
1.175 0
1.175 0
};
\addlegendentry{6 ACH};

\addplot [
color=black,
solid
]
table{
1.105 0
1.245 0
};
\addlegendentry{6 ACH};

\addplot [
color=black,
solid
]
table{
1.105 0
1.245 0
};
\addlegendentry{500 ACH};

\addplot [
color=black,
solid,
line width=1.0pt
]
table{
1.035 0
1.315 0
};
\addlegendentry{6 ACH};

\addplot [
color=blue,
only marks,
mark=*,
mark options={solid,fill=mycolor2,draw=black}
]
table{
1.175 10.6896518156056
};
\addlegendentry{6 ACH};


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Every `\addlegendentry` will produce a legend entry. This is more Matlab2TikZ’ wrong-doing than `pgfplots`’. Would manually removing the additional `\addlegendentry`s be a solution?

Comment: This is what I thiught too, but I cant seem to find the correct legend entry fornthe blue boxes. Can you replicate those using tikz commands of some sort?

Comment: You can use `area legend` for that. See the manual.

Comment: @percusse http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62262/legend-in-tikzpicture Shows a good example of your suggestion and it partially works. Is it possible to automatically position the legend depending on the size of the graph? I have 100 graphs of different sizes and it would be very teadious to work out the coordinates of the upper right corner for each one. Any thoughts? If you make this an answer I'll give you thumbs up. Cheers

Comment: Have you been able to solve this? I wasn't able to reproduce the problem, could you post the Matlab code as well? (You can replace your data with some random numbers.)

Comment: Why is this question closed "as unclear what you're asking"? Seems  clear to me.