# adding legend to a tikz graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, legend

I'm creating a picture through `tikz` package. It shows a eight spoke wagon wheel at two different frames. How can I add the legend __ Frame 1 and ....Frame 2?
When I try to use `\addlegendentry` it gives me an error. Thanks in advance

```
 \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
 \usepackage{tikz}

 \begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
   \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);

   \draw (0:1cm) -- (180:1cm);
   \draw (45:1cm) -- (225:1cm);
   \draw (90:1cm) -- (270:1cm);
   \draw (135:1cm) -- (315:1cm);

   \draw[dotted] (7.5:1cm) -- (187.5:1cm);
   \draw[dotted] (52.5:1cm) -- (232.5:1cm);
   \draw[dotted] (97.5:1cm) -- (277.5:1cm);
   \draw[dotted] (142.5:1cm) -- (322.5:1cm);
   \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. `\addlegendentry` is command from package `pgfplots`. If I correctly understand, what you like to obtain, than you can do with adding a node with desired description (legend). can you proved a sketch, where you like to have legend and what it is in in. Or, can be this legend part of caption?

Comment: @Zarko on the right and it should be something like..

___ Frame 1
.... Frame 2

Comment: See [Legend in tikzpicture](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62262/4778) and [Using a pgfplots-style legend in a plain-old tikzpicture](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54794/4778)

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image]

your question is not very clear, so this can  be only starting point... MWE, which gives above image is:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\node (n1) [circle,draw,minimum size=6cm] {};% node size can not be scaled
\node (n2) [draw,right=of n1,align=left] {- - - frame 1 \dots\\
                                          -----frame 2 \dots};  
\draw   (  0:1) -- (180:1)
        ( 45:1) -- (225:1)
        ( 90:1) -- (270:1)
        (135:1) -- (315:1);
\draw[dotted] 
        (  7.5:1) -- (187.5:1)
        ( 52.5:1) -- (232.5:1)
        ( 97.5:1) -- (277.5:1)
        (142.5:1) -- (322.5:1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks like that. This is already fine but why if I would like to use \addlegendentry it does not work?

Comment: I told you, that this command doesn't belong to TikZ. If you like to stick with it, you should use `pgfplots`.