# Tabular like legend in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend

I use `legend style={legend columns=*}` to create columns in my pgfplots legends. However, this options only changes the way legend entries are displayed. What I often need is to display various data for each plot, like in a table. Here is an example of the (ugly) work-around I use so far:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
title={$y=a \cdot x + b$},
xlabel=$x$,
ylabel=$y$,
legend pos=south east,
legend style={legend columns=2},
]

\addlegendimage{empty legend}
\addlegendimage{empty legend}
\addlegendentry{$\quad a \quad$} % \quad are just here to make columns wider... I suppose there's a better way
\addlegendentry{$\quad b \quad$}

\addplot+[domain=-1:2, samples=10] {3*x+1};
\addlegendimage{empty legend}
\addplot+[domain=-1:2, samples=10] {2*x+2};
\addlegendimage{empty legend}
\addplot+[domain=-1:2, samples=10] {1*x+3};
\addlegendimage{empty legend}

\addlegendentry{3}  % first data for the first graph
\addlegendentry{1}  % second data for the first graph
\addlegendentry{2}  % first data for the second graph
\addlegendentry{2}  % you've got it...
\addlegendentry{1}
\addlegendentry{3}

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: double entry legend]

I'd be grateful for any ideas to make the syntax cleaner and, above all, robust!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the easiest solution is to create your "legend" yourself with the `\matrix` command. To get the `\addplot` styles you just need to `\label` them accordingly and to recall them, use the `\ref` feature inside a `\matrix` cell.

For more details please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    % load `matrix' library so we can use the `matrix of nodes' feature
    \usetikzlibrary{
        matrix,
    }
    % use `compat' level 1.3 (or higher) to use the advanced placement features
    % for the axis labels
    \pgfplotsset{
        compat=1.3,
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            title={$y=a \cdot x + b$},
            xlabel=$x$,
            ylabel=$y$,
        ]
            \addplot+ [domain=-1:2, samples=10] {3*x+1};
                % add labels to the plots
                \label{plot:line1}
            \addplot+ [domain=-1:2, samples=10] {2*x+2};
                \label{plot:line2}
            \addplot+ [domain=-1:2, samples=10] {1*x+3};
                \label{plot:line3}

            % create a (dummy) coordinate where we want to place the legend
            %
            % (The matrix cannot be placed inside the `axis' environment
            %  directly, because then a catcode error is raised.
            %  I guess that this is caused by the `matrix of nodes' feature)
            \coordinate (legend) at (axis description cs:0.97,0.03);
        \end{axis}

        % create the legend matrix which is placed at the created (dummy) coordinate
        % and recall the plot specification using the `\ref' command
        %
        % adapt the style of that node to your needs
        % (e.g. if you like different spacings between the rows or columns)
        \matrix [
            draw,
            matrix of nodes,
            anchor=south east,
        ] at (legend) {
                             & $a$ & $b$ \\
            \ref{plot:line1} & 3   & 1   \\
            \ref{plot:line2} & 2   & 2   \\
            \ref{plot:line3} & 1   & 3   \\
        };

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Much cleaner indeed. Going a little bit further, I'm often using `\addlegendimage{*}` in my legends. With your method, I'd define a `\legendimage` by hand, mark it with a `\label` and call it in the matrix with `\ref`. Any ideas to make more straight foward?

Comment: Thanks for editing my answer. To your question: I am not sure if I have understood it right, but I would define a new legend style in the preamble like `line legend` (have a look in the PGFPlots manual how it is defined and adapt it) and then just use this legend later in the corresponding `\addplot`s. If I misunderstood your question, please just ask a follow-up question illustrating a bit more with an example.

Comment: done! I wanted to post the follow-up question first, but I didn't quite find the time this morning... Thanks for the remainder.

Comment: You are free to do it whenever you want ... :)

Comment: Now that you gave me the correct keywords, I was able to find a similar question/answer: (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278530/how-i-can-customize-a-legend-on-pgfplots/278538#278538). John Kormylo's syntax is slightly different, using `node` and `tabular` instead of `matrix`. Sounds like this question was a duplicate, with a more explicit title!

Comment: Indeed it seems that is was a duplicate. Shall we close this one then as duplicate?

Comment: You know better than me the rule of the house! I've found another similar question: (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127496/pgf-plots-and-a-tabular-legend).

Comment: I've posted the follow-up question: (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348375/creating-legend-images-for-tabular-legend-in-pgfplots). Hope it's more explicit!