# Creating legend images for tabular legend in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend

I use tabular legends for my graphs in pgfplots. At least three posts give ways to do that: [Tabular like legend](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348229/tabular-like-legend-in-pgfplots/348253#348253), 
[Custom legend](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278530/how-i-can-customize-a-legend-on-pgfplots/278538#278538) and [Tabular legend](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127496/pgf-plots-and-a-tabular-legend). I like the syntax where a `\label` is given to the curves, called in a `\matrix` after `\end{axis}`.

However, I often need to define the legend entries "by hand" with `\addlegendimage`, which is then labeled and reference to. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{
    matrix,
}
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=newest,
    every axis plot post/.append style={
        every mark/.append style={solid},        % avoid dashed markers
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
title={$y=a \cdot x + b$},
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$,
    ]
\addplot+[domain=-1:2, samples=10, mark=o, dashed] {1*x+1};
\addplot+[domain=-1:2, samples=10, mark=o, solid] {1*x+2};
\addplot+[domain=-1:2, samples=10, mark=square, dashed] {2*x+1};
\addplot+[domain=-1:2, samples=10, mark=square, solid] {2*x+2};

\addlegendimage{dashed}  % define by hand a legend image
\label{plot:dashed}      % label it
\addlegendimage{solid}
\label{plot:solid}
\addlegendimage{only marks, mark=o}
\label{plot:o}
\addlegendimage{only marks, mark=square}
\label{plot:square}
\coordinate (legend) at (axis description cs:1.03,1);
\end{axis}

\matrix[
    draw,
    matrix of nodes,
    anchor=north west,
]
at (legend) {
    Slope                   & $a$ & $1/a$   \\
    \ref{plot:o}            & 2   & 0.5     \\
    \ref{plot:square}       & 1   & 1       \\
    Origin                  & $b$ & $1/b$   \\
    \ref{plot:solid}        & 2   & 0.5     \\
    % call the image. It would better to create it by hand here, no? 
    \ref{plot:dashed}       & 1   & 1       \\
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: tabular legend with addlegendimage]

It sounds strange to define "by-hand" a `\addlegendimage` with a `\label` and then call it in the matrix with `\ref`.
As we're still in the tikzpicture, is there a command to directly generate the legend images within the matrix?

Comment: Maybe http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348129/include-plotmarks-in-the-title-of-a-plot is related. There it is explained how you get the plot mark and I think you know how to draw a line, right ;) Please let us know if we can close this question as a duplicate or if we shall provide an answer here.

Comment: @StefanPinnow Yep, definitely closely related. I can't get the vertical centering right in the matrix, but that's another problem. Thanks for the link, you can close this question!

Comment: I think the nodes are vertically and horizontally aligned by default, aren't they?  But in case you don't find out yourself: You are free to ask (another) follow-up question ;)