# Which LaTeX package is needed to draw radar-like diagrams?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, graphs, asymptote, charts

Can you please suggest some LaTeX package of drawing charts in the format mentioned below?

[image]

It should offer the possibility to put text as "Text A" as well as "Text B" .

Note: Currently I'm using TikZ to draw pie charts.

Comment: The `tikz` package is what you are looking for.
The manual has all the information you need to typeset this diagram. Can you post what you have so far? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Could you edit the title of your question to something more descriptive than "diagram attached", so other people have a chance to find the question if they need to do something similar?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

run with `xelatex` or `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)%             user coordinates (is cm by default)
\psaxes[labels=none,axesstyle=polar,ticklinestyle=dashed,tickcolor=black!40](0,0)(-4,-4)(4,4)
\psaxes(0,0)(-4,-4)(4,4)%                  for the labels
\psset{fillstyle=solid,opacity=0.5}
\pswedge[fillcolor=green]{2.2}{120}{150}%  radius;startAngle;endAngle
\pswedge[fillcolor=yellow]{1.5}{150}{180}
\pswedge[fillcolor=red]{1.25}{180}{210}
\pswedge[fillcolor=red]{1.8}{210}{240}
\pswedge[fillcolor=green!100!white!80]{1.5}{240}{270}
\pswedge[fillcolor=orange]{2.4}{270}{300}
\pswedge[fillcolor=magenta]{2.2}{300}{330}
\pswedge[fillcolor=cyan]{0.6}{330}{360}
\psset{opacity=1}
\rput*[r](0,-3){\textbf{\textsf{Test B}}}
\rput*[r](4.5;135){\textbf{\textsf{Test A}}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

a legend can be done in several ways. For examples:

```
%% the legend (after the last \pswedge)
\pswedge[fillcolor=green](4.25;90){0.5}{70}{110} \rput(4.9;90){foo}
\pswedge[fillcolor=yellow](4.25;80){0.5}{70}{110}\rput(4.9;80){bar}
\pswedge[fillcolor=red](4.25;70){0.5}{70}{110}   \rput(4.9;70){baz}
\pswedge[fillcolor=blue](4.25;60){0.5}{70}{110}  \rput[b](4.9;60){foobar}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Herbert, Can you please suggest, how can we add legand ?

Comment: see my edited answer

Answer (score 27):

The TikZ library `secdia` (I believe it stands for *sector-diagram*) can accomplish this task. It provides basically 3 commands:

1. `\drawaxes[list of options]{};` to establish the axis and the circles composing the grid;
2. `\sector[list of options]{}`; to draw a single sector;
3. `\sectorlist[list of options]{};` to draw automatically a diagram.

There is a number of options to customize the aspect of the diagram and there is a support for the legend: basically it is taken from [Using a pgfplots-style legend in a plain-old tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54794/using-a-pgfplots-style-legend-in-a-plain-old-tikzpicture#54834).

The code of the library (name of the file to be put in the same folder of the main `.tex` file: `tikzlibrarysecdia.code.tex`):

```
% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = 
% Sector diagram library 7/10/2013
% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = 
%\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc,shapes.geometric}
\pgfdeclarelayer{sector-back}
\pgfdeclarelayer{sector-middle}
\pgfsetlayers{sector-back,sector-middle,main}

\newcommand{\deflistentries}[1]{
\gdef\listentries{}% global list
\foreach \x[count=\xi] in {#1}{\global\let\maxitems\xi}% count the max number of items
\foreach \x[count=\xi] in {#1}{
 \ifnum\xi=\maxitems
   \xdef\listentries{\listentries \x}
 \else
   \xdef\listentries{\listentries \x,}
 \fi  
}
}
\newcommand{\deflistcolors}[1]{
\gdef\listcolors{}% global list
\foreach \x[count=\xi] in {#1}{\global\let\maxitemcolors\xi}% count the max number of items
\foreach \x[count=\xi] in {#1}{
 \ifnum\xi=\maxitemcolors
   \xdef\listcolors{\listcolors \x}
 \else
   \xdef\listcolors{\listcolors \x,}
 \fi  
}
}

% list of keys
\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
  diagram angle/.store in=\refangle,
  diagram angle=30,
  diagram radius/.store in=\diagramradius,
  diagram radius=5,
  diagram step/.store in=\diagramstep,
  diagram step=1,
  diagram axes precision/.store in=\diagramprecision,
  diagram axes precision=0,
  diagram x label/.store in=\diagramxlabel,
  diagram x label=Test A,
  diagram y label/.store in=\diagramylabel,
  diagram y label=Test B,
  diagram x label pos/.store in=\diagramxlabelpos,
  diagram x label pos=135:\diagramradius,
  diagram y label pos/.store in=\diagramylabelpos,
  diagram y label pos=270:\diagramradius,
  options x label/.store in=\diagramxoptions,
  options x label={},
  options y label/.store in=\diagramyoptions,
  options y label={},
  draw axes/.code={
    \pgfmathsetmacro\diagramsecondstep{2*\diagramstep}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{sector-back}
    \foreach \angle in {0,\refangle,...,360}{
      \draw[help lines,dashed](0,0) --++(\angle:\diagramradius);
    }
    \draw(-\diagramradius,0)--(\diagramradius,0);
    \draw(0,-\diagramradius)--(0,\diagramradius);
    \foreach \x in {\diagramstep,\diagramsecondstep,...,\diagramradius}{
      \draw[help lines,dashed](0,0) circle[radius=\x];
      \draw(\x,0.1)--(\x,-0.1);
      \draw(0.1,\x)--(-0.1,\x);
      \draw(-\x,0.1)--(-\x,-0.1);
      \draw(0.1,-\x)--(-0.1,-\x);
    }
    \end{pgfonlayer}

     \foreach \x in {\diagramstep,\diagramsecondstep,...,\diagramradius}{ 
      \node[fill=white,draw,inner sep=1.5pt,font=\footnotesize] at (0,\x)
      {\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,
        precision=\diagramprecision,
        fixed zerofill,
      ]{\x}};
    }
    \node[fill=white,draw,inner sep=1.5pt] at (0,0){0};
    \node[fill=white,\diagramxoptions] at (\diagramxlabelpos){\diagramxlabel};
    \node[fill=white,\diagramyoptions] at (\diagramylabelpos){\diagramylabel};
  },
  sector angle/.store in=\sectorangle,
  sector angle=\refangle,
  sector color/.store in=\sectorcolor,
  sector color=green!80!black,
  sector opacity/.store in=\sectoropacity,
  sector opacity=0.8,
  sector amplitude/.store in=\sectoramplitude,
  sector amplitude=1cm,
  sector rotation/.store in=\sectorrotation,
  sector rotation=\sectorangle/2,
  sector amplitude=1,
  draw sector/.code={
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{sector-middle}
    \node[circular sector,
          draw,
          fill=\sectorcolor,
          opacity=\sectoropacity,
          circular sector angle=\sectorangle,
          anchor=sector center,
          minimum width=\sectoramplitude,
          rotate=\sectorrotation] 
          at (0,0){};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
  },
  draw sector list/.code={
    \foreach \ampli/\thiscolor[count=\xi from 0] in {#1}{
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro\thisrotation{\sectorangle/2+\xi*\sectorangle}
            \sector[sector color=\thiscolor,
               sector amplitude=\ampli,
               sector rotation=\thisrotation,
               draw sector]{};
    }
  },
}

\tikzset{sector legend/.style={
  circular sector,
  draw,
  opacity=\sectoropacity
  }
}
% definition to insert numbers
\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/sector in legend/.style={%
        /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
            \node[sector legend,#1] at (0,0){}; 
        },%
    },
}

% main commands
\def\drawaxes{\tikz@path@overlay{node}}
\def\sector{\tikz@path@overlay{node}}
\def\sectorlist{\tikz@path@overlay{node}}
\def\sectorlegendimage#1{\addlegendimage{sector in legend={#1}}}
\def\legendlistcolors#1{%
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{#1}{
\sectorlegendimage{fill=##1}}
}

% legend stuff
%%--------------------------------
% Code from Christian Feuersänger
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54794/using-a-pgfplots-style-legend-in-a-plain-old-tikzpicture#54834

% argument #1: any options
\newenvironment{customlegend}[1][]{%
    \begingroup
    % inits/clears the lists (which might be populated from previous
    % axes):
    \csname pgfplots@init@cleared@structures\endcsname
    \pgfplotsset{#1}%
}{%
    % draws the legend:
    \csname pgfplots@createlegend\endcsname
    \endgroup
}%

% makes \addlegendimage available (typically only available within an
% axis environment):
\def\addlegendimage{\csname pgfplots@addlegendimage\endcsname}

%%--------------------------------
```

An example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,png]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots} % it is required for the legend
\usetikzlibrary{secdia}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\drawaxes[diagram angle=15,diagram radius=4,draw axes]{};
% to draw a single sector
\sector[sector rotation=-45,
  sector angle=30,
  sector amplitude=3.5cm,
  draw sector]{};
\sector[sector rotation=-15,
  sector angle=30,
  sector amplitude=2.5cm,
  sector color=yellow,
  draw sector]{};
% to draw a list of sectors
\sectorlist[sector angle=30,
draw sector list={2cm/red,
  3cm/blue,
  2.5cm/green,
  4cm/orange,
  3.5cm/purple!70!magenta,
  2/cyan}]{};
% to add a legend

\begin{customlegend}[
legend entries={
Something A,Something A,Something A,Something A,Something A,Something A
},
legend style={at={(4,2)},anchor=south west}]
\legendlistcolors{red,blue,green,orange,purple,cyan}
\end{customlegend}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Application to the OP reference image:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,png]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{secdia}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\drawaxes[diagram angle=15,diagram radius=4,draw axes]{};
% to draw a list of sectors
\sectorlist[sector angle=30,
draw sector list={2cm/red!90!blue,
  2.5cm/magenta,
  3.5cm/magenta!40!violet,
  3cm/violet!50!blue,
  3cm/blue!80!cyan,
  2.5cm/blue!20!cyan,
  3cm/cyan!50!green,
  3cm/green!85!blue,
  2.5cm/green!90!lime,
  3.5cm/yellow,
  3.5cm/orange,
  2cm/red!70!orange}]{};
% to add a legend

\begin{customlegend}[
legend entries={
Something 1,Something 2,Something 3,Something 4,Something 5,Something 6,
Something 7,Something 8,Something 9,Something 10,Something 11,Something 12
},
legend style={at={(4.5,0)},anchor=south west,font=\scriptsize}]
\legendlistcolors{red!90!blue,magenta,magenta!40!violet,violet!50!blue,blue!80!cyan,blue!20!cyan,cyan!50!green,green!85!blue,green!90!lime,yellow,orange,red!70!orange}
\end{customlegend}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Claudio, Can you please suggest, how can we add legand ?

Comment: The library handles this ( theoretically speaking there will be some improvement for automatic insertion ;))

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. This really helps. Currently in a report i'm already using pst-plot package (so I'll continue with Herbert's answer) . This answer is very much useful. Regards, Pawan

Comment: Notice that the scale of values is completely off. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: @AdamErickson: not quite sure.. what do you mean?

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino It looks like the magnitude of sector values is too low in the figure. Nothing gets close to 3. Unless I am missing something?

Comment: @AdamErickson: I believe it was only an example where I changed the parameters. Did you try with other values? If yes, and there's a problem, maybe you can open a follow-up question and I'll try to have a look

Answer (score 20):

[image]

`MWE` with `Asymptote`. Text can be added with function `putText`,
the legend is written next to the data sector.

```
% radar.tex:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\begin{asydef}
struct RadarPlot{

  real[] data;
  string[] Legend;
  pen[] Pens;
  pen gridPen;
  pen axisPen;
  pen labelPen;
  pen legendPen;
  int n,m;
  real pieAngle;
  int maxX;
  int maxY;
  real step;
  real Step;
  pair O=(0,0);

  void drawSectors(){
    guide g;
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
      g=arc(0,data[i],i*pieAngle,(i+1)*pieAngle);
      fill(O--g--cycle,Pens[i%m]);
    }
  }   

  void drawGrid(){
    for(int i=1;i<=(int)(maxY/step);++i){
      draw(circle(O,i*step),gridPen);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<maxX;++i){
      draw(rotate(i*360/maxX)*(O--(maxY,0)),gridPen);
    }
  }

  void drawAxes(){
    draw((-maxY,0)--(maxY,0),axisPen);
    draw((0,-maxY)--(0,maxY),axisPen);
  }

  void drawLabels(){
    for(int i=1;i<=(int)(maxY/Step);++i){
      draw(Label(string(i*Step),(0,i*Step)),roundbox,filltype=UnFill,labelPen);
      draw(Label(string(i*Step),(0,-i*Step)),roundbox,filltype=UnFill,labelPen);
      draw(Label(string(i*Step),(-i*Step,0)),roundbox,filltype=UnFill,labelPen);
      draw(Label(string(i*Step),(i*Step,0)),roundbox,filltype=UnFill,labelPen);
    }
  }

  void drawLegend(){
    transform t;
    real a;
    pair v;
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
      a=(i+0.5)*pieAngle;
      t=rotate(a);
      v=t*(data[i],0);
      if(a<90 || a>270){
        label(t*Legend[i],v,unit(v),legendPen);
      }else{
        label(rotate(a-180)*Legend[i],v,unit(v),legendPen);        
      }

    }
  }

  void draw(){
    drawGrid();
    drawSectors();
    drawAxes();
    drawLabels();
    drawLegend();
  }  

  void putText(string s, real x, real y, pair pos=O, pen p=currentpen){
    label(s,rotate(x*pieAngle)*(y,0),pos,p);
  }

  void operator init(real[] data, string[] Legend, pen[] Pens
    ,int maxX=2data.length
    ,int maxY=(int)max(data)+1
    ,pen gridPen=rgb(0.812,0.8,0.776)
    ,pen axisPen=darkblue
    ,pen labelPen=deepblue
    ,pen legendPen=deepgreen
    ,real step=1
    ,real Step=2step
  ){
    this.data=copy(data);
    this.Pens=copy(Pens);
    this.Legend=copy(Legend);

    this.n=data.length;
    this.m=Pens.length;
    this.pieAngle=360/n;
    this.maxX=maxX;
    this.maxY=maxY;
    this.gridPen=gridPen;
    this.axisPen=axisPen;
    this.labelPen=labelPen;
    this.legendPen=legendPen;
    this.step=step;
    this.Step=Step;
  }

};
\end{asydef}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{asy}
settings.outformat="pdf";
size(300);

real[] data={
5,
5,
4,
5,
5,
4,
4,
5,
6,
5,
5,
4,
};

pen op=opacity(0.8);

pen[] Pens={
op+rgb(0,0.91,0.769),
op+rgb(0.298,0.835,0.549),
op+rgb(0.365,0.906,0.408),
op+rgb(0.973,0.965,0.333),
op+rgb(1,0.812,0.298),
op+rgb(1,0.463,0.302),
op+rgb(1,0.318,0.447),
op+rgb(1,0.322,0.749),
op+rgb(0.875,0.337,0.91),
op+rgb(0.702,0.349,0.914),
op+rgb(0.294,0.482,0.922),
op+rgb(0,0.804,0.929),
};


string[] Legend={
"set A",
"set B",
"set C",
"set D",
"set E",
"set F",
"set G",
"set H",
"set I",
"set J",
"set K",
"set L",
};

RadarPlot rp=RadarPlot(data,Legend,Pens,maxY=9,Step=3);

rp.draw();
rp.putText("Test A",4.5,10);
rp.putText("Test B",9  , 8,W);

\end{asy}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
%
% Process:
%
% pdflatex radar.tex    
% asy radar-*.asy   
% pdflatex radar.tex
```

Comment: Thanks g.kov for your answer. Currently in a report i'm already using pst-plot package (so I'll continue with Herbert's answer).

Answer (score 5):

The [wheelchart](https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) package, which I wrote, can be used.

The legend is determined by the key `legend`. This is a `tabular` which is placed in a `\node`. The rows are determined by the key `legend row`. The result of all rows can be obtained with `\WClegend`.

The first variable `\WCvarA` is used for the outer radius of the slices. Furthermore, `value=1` so that the angle of each slice is the same.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\wheelchart[
  data=,
  legend row={\tikz\fill[\WCvarB] (0,0) rectangle (0.3,0.3); & \WCvarC},
  legend={\node[right] at (10,0) {\begin{tabular}{l@{ }l}\WClegend\end{tabular}};},
  radius={0}{\WCvarA},
  value=1
]{%
  4/green/A,
  5/green!50!black/B,
  5/teal!70/C,
  4/cyan/D,
  5/blue/E,
  5/violet/F,
  6/purple/G,
  5/magenta/H,
  4/red/I,
  4/orange/J,
  5/orange!50!yellow/K,
  5/yellow/L%
}
\foreach\r in {1,...,9}{
  \draw[gray] (0,0) circle[radius=\r];
}
\foreach\a in {0,30,...,150}{
  \draw[gray] (\a:-9)--(\a:9);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `wheelchart` package never ceases to amaze me. You are such an awesome contributor