# How to draw legend lines in caption/text without including original plot's TikZ picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, cross-referencing

I would like to reference some plot lines in text/captions. It is possible by defining a label for the plot in the corresponding `axis` environment. However, I'm using externalization and only want to distribute the PDF files (not the `tikzpicture` files), but still want to reference plot lines in the text. How to separately add labels for the plot line without having to include the whole `tikzpicture`?

As a workaround, I include dummy plots and label them, but it results in appearing a dot in the document. Any way to make this `tikzpicture` hidden and taking zero space would also be useful.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
This is how I reference to \ref{hwplot1} and \ref{hwplot2}. But the following 'tikzpicture' results in ploting a dot


%%% This is neccessary for drawing plot lines in the text
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[hide axis]
        \addplot [
        color=red,
        solid,
        line width=0.9pt,
        forget plot
        ]
        (0,0);\label{hwplot1}
        \addplot [
        color=black,
        dashed,
        line width=1.2pt,
        forget plot
        ]
        (0,0);\label{hwplot2}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: It might be easier to create you own legend from scratch.  It's just a box with tome lines and labels.

Comment: Possibly related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54794/using-a-pgfplots-style-legend-in-a-plain-old-tikzpicture/54834#54834

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by referencing plot lines in the text?  If you want to illustrate a particular line you can always use something like \tikz{\draw[red] (0,0) -- (5mm,0);} or define a macro if you plan to do it a lot.

Comment: Never mind.  I ran you MWE.  Cute!

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\hwplotA}{\raisebox{2pt}{\tikz{\draw[red,solid,line width=0.9pt](0,0) -- (5mm,0);}}}
\newcommand{\hwplotB}{\raisebox{2pt}{\tikz{\draw[black,dashed,line width=1.2pt](0,0) -- (5mm,0);}}}

This is how I reference to {\hwplotA} and {\hwplotB}. 

\end{document}
```

[image: inserted lines]

---

When in doubt, use a savebox.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\hwplotA}{\raisebox{2pt}{\tikz{\draw[red,solid,line width=0.9pt](0,0) -- (5mm,0);}}}
\newcommand{\hwplotB}{\raisebox{2pt}{\tikz{\draw[black,dashed,line width=1.2pt](0,0) -- (5mm,0);}}}

\begin{figure}[hp]
\sbox0{\hwplotA}\sbox1{\hwplotB}%
\caption{This is how I reference to \usebox0 and \usebox1.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I would like to have a inline reference to plot lines as what the MWE does. but without having to include the `tikzpicture` or at least make it invisible.

Comment: I replaced the original answer with something more appropriate.  BTW, you can't label macros with numbers, so I used letters.

Comment: This doesn't work in a caption.

Comment: @Tropilio - Interesting!  I wonder if this is new or has always been a problem?

Comment: @JohnKormylo I don't know, but I discovered that changing `\newcommand` to `\DeclareRobustCommand` solves the problem.

Comment: @Tropilio: `\DeclareRobustCommand` seems to solve the problem

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't eliminate the `tikz` picture, but it scales it to zero size.  Here, it is placed in the middle of the last word "nothing".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
This is how I reference to \ref{hwplot1} and \ref{hwplot2}. But the following
  'tikzpicture' results in plotting no%
%%% This is neccessary for drawing plot lines in the text
\scalebox{0}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[hide axis]
        \addplot [
        color=red,
        solid,
        line width=0.9pt,
        forget plot
        ]
        (0,0);\label{hwplot1}
        \addplot [
        color=black,
        dashed,
        line width=1.2pt,
        forget plot
        ]
        (0,0);\label{hwplot2}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}%
thing
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think this would still create a file when externalized.

Comment: indeed not, unless some measures are taken: "a `\ref` inside of an externalized graphics works only if you issue the required system call
manually or by `make`."

Answer (score 2):

For my and others future reference, I have taken the excellent example by @steven-b-segletes and generalised it for the automated creation of labels from a cycle list. 
This is great for reusing labels where you have the legend in a caption, or are using the animate package and dont want 300 repeated references

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\graphlinewidth}{1}
\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{mylistNoMarkDarkColour}{%
  {red!80!black,    solid,      line width=\graphlinewidth, mark=none},
  {green!80!black,  solid,      line width=\graphlinewidth, mark=none},
  {blue,    solid,          line width=\graphlinewidth, mark=none},
  {purple,  solid,          line width=\graphlinewidth, mark=none},
  {orange,  solid,          line width=\graphlinewidth, mark=none},
}

% Generate the label references for legends in captions from the given cyle list and reference.
% Also avoids issues with TiKz externalize
% 1: Cycle list name, 2: Reference prefix, 3: Number to produce
\newcommand{\pgfplotsReferenceGenerator}[3]{%
\scalebox{0}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[hide axis, cycle list name = #1]
  \foreach \i   [evaluate=\i] in {1,...,#2}{
    \addplot (0,0); \label{#3\i}
  }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}%
}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsReferenceGenerator{mylistNoMarkDarkColour}{5}{dark}
This is great for reusing labels where you have the legend in a caption,
or are using the animate package and dont want 300 repeated references (i.e one \ref{dark1} per frame)
like \ref{dark2} and \ref{dark3} with \ref{dark4} finally \ref{dark5}

\end{document}
```

What I have not been able to do and would appreciate feedback on:

1. Automatically detect the length of the cycle list
2. Correctly disable TiKz externalisation for the graph (I couldn't make it work...)
   [image]