# How to create legend lines with a marker in a figure caption

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to create a legend for use in the caption of a plot (to match a plot created in matlab, so sadly, I can't just link to the figure.).  I know that tikz can create values for use in a legend, as in the MWE included below.  But what I really want is to also have a marker symbol:  a dashed line with a circle -o-

I think maybe I would want to add a node  (e.g., draw a short line, draw a symbol, draw another short line).  So then this would give me something like

```
\newcommand{\hwplotA}{\raisebox{2pt}{\tikz{\draw[black,dashed,mark=o,line width=0.9pt](0,0) -- (5mm,0);\node at (2.5mm,0) {$o$}}}}
```

although this doesn't compile.   The solution listed by the OP at the link below doesn't work for me (putting a zero-sized tikz plot) because it seems to not play nicely with other packages I'm using.

Any ideas?

MWE to create a legend line from [How to draw legend lines in caption/text without including original plot's TikZ picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148681/how-to-draw-legend-lines-in-caption-text-without-including-original-plots-tikz)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\hwplotA}{\raisebox{2pt}{\tikz{\draw[red,solid,line width=0.9pt](0,0) -- (5mm,0);}}}
\newcommand{\hwplotB}{\raisebox{2pt}{\tikz{\draw[black,dashed,line width=1.2pt](0,0) -- (5mm,0);}}}

This is how I reference to {\hwplotA} and {\hwplotB}. 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To illustrate Christian Feuersänger's solution from [Using a pgfplots-style legend in a plain-old tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54794/using-a-pgfplots-style-legend-in-a-plain-old-tikzpicture?s=1|1.6766) :

Do you really want the legend in the caption?  Between the picture and the caption should do.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\makeatletter
% argument #1: any options
\newenvironment{customlegend}[1][]{%
    \begingroup
    \let\addlegendimage=\pgfplots@addlegendimage
    \let\addlegendentry=\pgfplots@addlegendentry
    % inits/clears the lists (which might be populated from previous axes):
    \pgfplots@init@cleared@structures
    \pgfplotsset{#1}%
}{%
    % draws the legend:
    \pgfplots@createlegend
    \endgroup
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{customlegend}[legend columns=-1]
\addlegendimage{red,mark=*}
\addlegendentry{raw data}
\addlegendimage{blue,mark=triangle*}
\addlegendentry{cooked data}
\end{customlegend}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: legend]

Comment: Hmm, that's a nice workaround.  Ideally, I would like to find a solution that also works in the caption.

Comment: You can put it in the caption, but it will also show up in the list of figures.