# plotted caption

Tags: captions

I have a plot as

[image]

Please take attention to this caption:

`In this plot purple dashed curve shows the behavior of ..... Long dashed curve shows... and straight line exhibits...`

How can I write a caption in which, instead of writing `purple dashed`, I use a line with that characteristic for example:
[image]

We can use legend for curves in plots but by using them, they may exhibited in a messy way.

Comment: How do you add your plot to your document? Do you include it as an image or do you plot it using latex (e.g. using `pgfplots`)?

Comment: I have inserted as an image. I did not create with latex.

Comment: Probably duplicate of [pgfplots - How to draw legend lines in caption/text without including original plot's TikZ picture? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148681/how-to-draw-legend-lines-in-caption-text-without-including-original-plots-tikz) ; but if you don't include your code we won't know which package you use (and using a different package may make the style different

Comment: The link you addressed was very helpful. Thank you so much.