# How to draw a bubble column chart with a legend?

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, legend

I am very new to plot in Latex, and am trying to piece together a bubble column chart with a legend and labelled axes. So far, I have a working chart, but can only get the legend *or* a labeled x-axis.

I think I've probably done this the hard way. I had dummy `\addplot` to force a legend, but that removes the axis tick labels. Is there a fix to this, or just a better way to do this?

(uncomment the two line to get the x-axis tick labels without the legend)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\newif\iflegend
%\legendtrue

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
1 25 1 1
1 39 0.989010989 2
2 40 0.673629243 3
2 13 0.499013807 4
4 37 0.575 5
5 98 0.994505495 2
5 108 0.64229765 3
5 6 0.583333333 5
6 1 0.96 1
6 6 0.972527473 2
6 14 0.454308094 3
7 15 0.58382643 4
7 6 0.583333333 5
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[y=.5cm]
\pgfplotstableread{data.dat}\table
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\table}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\M}{\pgfplotsretval-1}
\pgfplotstablegetcolsof{\table}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\N}{\pgfplotsretval-1}

\definecolor{color0}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{255,0,0}
\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{0,255,0}
\definecolor{color3}{RGB}{150,255,200}
\definecolor{color4}{RGB}{200,200,90}
\definecolor{color5}{RGB}{100,0,200}
\definecolor{color6}{RGB}{190,0,190}

\begin{axis}[
    scatter,
    axis lines=left,
    ylabel=Training Time,
    every axis/.append style={font=\tiny},
    x axis line style=-,
    y axis line style=-,
    xtick=data,
    xticklabels={,,Label 1,Label 2,Label 3,Label 4,Label 5},
    xticklabel style={align=left},
    width=8.6cm,
    height=9.2cm,
    xmin=0, xmax=5,
    ymin=0, ymax=110,
    legend style={
        at={(0,0)},
        anchor=south west,
        at={(axis description cs:0.15,-0.35)},
        draw=none   % no border
    },
%    legend entries={baseline,legend1,legend3,legend4,legend5,legend6},
    scatter/@pre marker code/.code={%
      \pgfplotstransformcoordinatex{\pgfplotspointmeta}%
      \scope[mark size=\pgfplotsunitxlength*\pgfmathresult]
    }
]

\iflegend
\addplot +[bar shift, area legend, color=color0] coordinates {(6,0.001)};
\addplot +[bar shift, area legend, color=color1, fill, opacity=.5] coordinates {(0,.01)};
\addplot +[bar shift, area legend, color=color2, fill, opacity=.5] coordinates {(0,.01)};
\addplot +[bar shift, area legend, color=color3, fill, opacity=.5] coordinates {(0,.01)};
\addplot +[bar shift, area legend, color=color4, fill, opacity=.5] coordinates {(0,.01)};
\addplot +[bar shift, area legend, color=color5, fill, opacity=.5, solid] coordinates {(0,.01)};
\addplot +[bar shift, area legend, color=color6, fill, opacity=.5, solid] coordinates {(0,.01)};
\fi
\end{axis}

\foreach \row in {0,...,\M}{
    \foreach \col in {0,...,\N}{
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{[index]\col}\of\table
        \ifnum\col=3    % video
            \xdef\x{\pgfplotsretval}
        \fi
        \ifnum\col=1    % time
            \xdef\y{\pgfplotsretval}
        \fi
        \ifnum\col=2    % accuracy
            \xdef\radius{\pgfplotsretval}
        \fi
        \ifnum\col=0    % method
            \xdef\category{\pgfplotsretval}
        \fi
    }
    \ifnum\category=1
        \definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{0,0,0}
    \else\ifnum\category=2
        \definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{255,0,0}
    \else \ifnum\category=3
        \definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{0,255,0}
    \else\ifnum\category=4
        \definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{150,255,200}
    \else\ifnum\category=5
        \definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{200,200,90}
    \else\ifnum\category=6
        \definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{100,0,200}
    \else\ifnum\category=7
        \definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{190,0,190}
    \else \definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{128,128,128}
    \fi
    \fi
    \fi
    \fi
    \fi
    \fi
    \fi
\ifnum\category=1
\draw[mycolor] (\x*1.41,1+\y/8)circle(\radius*5mm);
\else
\fill[mycolor,opacity=.5] (\x*1.41,1+\y/8)circle(\radius*5mm);
\fi
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since your legend is created independently of the plot, you might look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54794/using-a-pgfplots-style-legend-in-a-plain-old-tikzpicture/148855#148855

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that you are doing a little too hard. pgfplots already offers some alternative mechanisms that come pretty close.

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents} 
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
met time acc video
1 25 1 1
1 39 0.989010989 2
2 40 0.673629243 3
2 13 0.499013807 4
4 37 0.575 5
5 98 0.994505495 2
5 108 0.64229765 3
5 6 0.583333333 5
6 1 0.96 1
6 6 0.972527473 2
6 14 0.454308094 3
7 15 0.58382643 4
7 6 0.583333333 5
\end{filecontents*}

\definecolor{color3}{RGB}{150,255,200}
\definecolor{color4}{RGB}{200,200,90}
\definecolor{color5}{RGB}{100,0,200}
\definecolor{color6}{RGB}{190,0,190}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=left,
    ylabel=Training Time,
    every axis/.append style={font=\tiny},
    x axis line style=-,
    y axis line style=-,
    xtick=data,
    xticklabels={Label 1,Label 2,Label 3,Label 4,Label 5},
    xticklabel style={align=left},
    width=8.6cm,
    height=9.2cm,
    xmin=0, xmax=5,
    ymin=0, ymax=110,
    legend style={
        at={(0,0)},
        anchor=south west,
        at={(axis description cs:0.15,-0.35)},
        draw=none   % no border
    },
    legend entries={legend1,legend2,legend3,legend4,legend5},
    only marks,
    %legend image post style={only marks},
scatter/classes={
    1={draw=black,fill=white},
    2={fill=red},
    3={green},% etc. etc.
    4={color3},
    5={color4},
    6={color5},
    7={color6}
  },
  visualization depends on= 10*\thisrow{acc} \as\myrad,
  scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/tikz/mark size=\myrad}
]
\addplot[scatter,scatter src=explicit,mark=*] table[x =video,y=time,meta=met] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can I add a scale to the circles so they appear bigger but inside the same axis footprint?

Comment: @cmdh change the factor 10 as you wish