# How to only show legend in pgf plot?

Tags: pgfplots, legend

I have created with matlab2tikz a standalone picture, saved in myfile.tikz

Here is the code:

```
  % This file was created by matlab2tikz v0.5.0 running on MATLAB 8.4.
%Copyright (c) 2008--2014, Nico Schlömer <nico.schloemer@gmail.com>
%All rights reserved.
%Minimal pgfplots version: 1.3
%
%The latest updates can be retrieved from
%  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz
%where you can also make suggestions and rate matlab2tikz.
%
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{grffile}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=5.828221in,
height=4.83871in,
  y tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
            fixed,
            precision=2,
        /tikz/.cd
    },
at={(0in,0in)},
xlabel={Amount of trajectories $(\times 10^7 )$},
ylabel={4th largest eigenvalue},
scale only axis,
separate axis lines,
every outer x axis line/.append style={white!15!black},
every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
xmin=10,
xmax=50,
every outer y axis line/.append style={white!15!black},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
ymin=0,
ymax=0.4,
legend style={draw=white!15!black,legend cell align=left}
]
\addplot [color=red,solid,mark=square*,mark options={solid,fill=red}]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
10  0.263363834999385\\
11  0.267956137706241\\
12  0.234749040704818\\
13  0.179095397783884\\
14  0.15598488764853\\
15  0.107130784874058\\
16  0.102335812851717\\
17  0.15130873420001\\
18  0.13294322038256\\
19  0.0960614078900675\\
20  0.0668875403805097\\
21  0.0696202544023205\\
22  0.0769402122493772\\
23  0.0814760237222062\\
24  0.0697776185374109\\
25  0.0890537892164226\\
26  0.0966623314755249\\
27  0.0934599345653749\\
28  0.0878880498733259\\
29  0.087473866000113\\
30  0.0892704892496597\\
31  0.0812007102089455\\
32  0.0785448212326198\\
33  0.0772843849145571\\
34  0.0748381690948553\\
35  0.076911866585151\\
36  0.0690916321763139\\
37  0.0681618703751155\\
38  0.0538871718086814\\
39  0.0462813570913469\\
40  0.042327952187128\\
41  0.0545656572749185\\
42  0.0502509655943423\\
43  0.0548481613029811\\
44  0.0565260239184772\\
45  0.0574958892089851\\
46  0.0565141460485921\\
47  0.0607219533955611\\
48  0.0621210992930102\\
49  0.0584171708241252\\
50  0.0554092144619335\\
};
\addlegendentry{Standart estimation};

\addplot [color=blue,dash pattern=on 1pt off 3pt on 3pt off 3pt,mark=asterisk,mark options={solid}]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
10  0.357550039744943\\
11  0.356972039378709\\
12  0.334368502350565\\
13  0.30613803777209\\
14  0.298223941905334\\
15  0.343030324802327\\
16  0.344206127225485\\
17  0.342654565258385\\
18  0.26909949152418\\
19  0.244071723963408\\
20  0.242341053266382\\
21  0.242231681701872\\
22  0.23431468104395\\
23  0.234032984140502\\
24  0.225001418677598\\
25  0.187193611177314\\
26  0.195346678096106\\
27  0.194987732958593\\
28  0.193281499543124\\
29  0.193039372776092\\
30  0.188745282175345\\
31  0.18389991087615\\
32  0.184250604858391\\
33  0.18358622178072\\
34  0.183425365322753\\
35  0.183581339448476\\
36  0.169460638908507\\
37  0.166155309985801\\
38  0.160320243705676\\
39  0.14731116222724\\
40  0.144469472179117\\
41  0.143751331186272\\
42  0.143538751559955\\
43  0.142526804916181\\
44  0.142099807792203\\
45  0.142164474247563\\
46  0.137436117746078\\
47  0.13816942742473\\
48  0.137543995531934\\
49  0.137932768120272\\
50  0.137592136659409\\
};
\addlegendentry{Corrected Frobenius estimation};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

In my terminal, I can produce a pdf file of my picture by entering

```
pdflatex myfile.tikz
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

I want to produce a PDF file only containing the legend of the pgfplot. Is this possible?

Edit: I would like to have this outcome:

[image]

Whereas LaRiFaRi's solution provides this:

[image]

How can I get the first picture? Do I need to trial-and-error or is there a shorter version for it? Removing `xmax`, `ymax`, `xmin` and `ymin` produced an empty image.

Comment: You mean without the plot?

Comment: @HarishKumar yes!

Comment: Which version of `pgfplots` are you using? If you don't know, please add `\listfiles` to your preamble and check the `.log` file for "pgfplots"

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54794/using-a-pgfplots-style-legend-in-a-plain-old-tikzpicture

Answer (score 14):

I do not know, why we need `xmin`, `xmax`, ... here, but well, it works (at least I hope this is what you have wanted):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[%
    hide axis,
    xmin=10,
    xmax=50,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=0.4,
    legend style={draw=white!15!black,legend cell align=left}
    ]
    \addlegendimage{red,mark=square*}
    \addlegendentry{Standart estimation};
    \addlegendimage{blue,dash pattern=on 1pt off 3pt on 3pt off 3pt,mark=asterisk,mark options={solid}}
    \addlegendentry{Corrected Frobenius estimation};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

NB: Try to use the `compat` parameter with your actual version.

Comment: Thank you, this is almost what I am looking for. I had to use compat=newest to get it working. However, I would like to have the image without additional empty space (see above edit). Still, thank you for this.

Comment: @Adam Replace `newest` by the version you actually have. This is better practise. Did you compile my very example? I do not see any white space around it. It is cropped to zero border.

Comment: yes I compiled your very example. Strange. I am using pgfplot version 1.7, maybe thats the reason for the white space in my outcome.. I dont know.

Comment: @Adam at least it is really old. We are on 1.12 right now. (or higher... haven't checked in the last time). Please try to update your system before we continue on this.