# Row sep in Tikz for a single row of a legend

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm using the legend-only solution from [Using a pgfplots-style legend in a plain-old tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54794/using-a-pgfplots-style-legend-in-a-plain-old-tikzpicture)

How can I get a style for a single row? I'm trying to have `row sep = 5pt` for example for all rows, but between the second and third row have a different value. I've tried

```
legend style={row sep = 5pt,
    /tikz/row 2/.style={row sep = 10pt}
}
```

This compiles fine and adds a `5pt` separation to all rows, but it doesn't change the separation after the second row.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Here's a MWE. I've simple copied the answer in the link and added the code above:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

% argument #1: any options
\newenvironment{customlegend}[1][]{%
    \begingroup
    % inits/clears the lists (which might be populated from previous
    % axes):
    \csname pgfplots@init@cleared@structures\endcsname
    \pgfplotsset{#1}%
}{%
    % draws the legend:
    \csname pgfplots@createlegend\endcsname
    \endgroup
}%

% makes \addlegendimage available (typically only available within an
% axis environment):
\def\addlegendimage{\csname pgfplots@addlegendimage\endcsname}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{customlegend}[legend style={row sep = 5pt,
        /tikz/row 2/.style={row sep = 10pt}
    },
    legend entries={$a$,$e^x$,C,$d$}]
    \addlegendimage{red,fill=black!50!red,area legend}
    \addlegendimage{red,fill=black!50!red,sharp plot}
    \addlegendimage{red,fill=black!50!red,mark=*,sharp plot}
    \addlegendimage{red,fill=black!50!red,ybar,ybar legend}
    \end{customlegend}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. If you want to set a style for a single row, then you want that style to apply to that row and just that row. So you don't want it to apply to any other rows. But that is what you say the problem is. Also, please remember that questions should include a complete minimal example and not just a code fragment, which is generally not very useful.

Comment: @cfr, the MWE is the same as the linked answer. What I'm looking for is a single `row sep` for every row except one, which I would like to be different. I am trying to set it to be different for a single row, but don't know how. The problem is that what I wrote doesn't work - it compiles without complaining, but leaves all the rows with the same `row sep`.

Comment: You didn't link to an answer. You linked to a question with multiple answers. But thank you for adding the example here.

Comment: `row sep` is not a documented key for `legend style` as far as I can tell. The `pgfplots` manual only seems to mention it for `table`. Why do you think this should work? Does it work in legends for regular `pgfplots` plots?

Comment: @cfr See 4.9.5 "Legend Appearance", p. 237, pgfplots manual v1.13: _The legend is a TikZ-matrix, so one can use any TikZ option which affects nodes and matrices..._

Comment: @PaulGaborit Thanks. I was actually writing an answer including that information while you were commenting, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`row sep` is passed as an option to the TikZ matrix which `pgfplots` uses to create the legend. This works fine, I think. However, it is an option which applies to *rows* and not to *cells*, whereas `row <number>` affects the style of *cells*. So setting `row sep` in the style `row 2` does nothing because individual *cells* aren't affected by this option at all.

You can approximate the effect by shifting all *cells* in a row using `yshift`, for example. Because `yshift` applies to *cells*, setting this in `row 2`'s style options *does* work.

For example (exaggerated for purposes of illustration):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
% code from Christian Feuersänger's answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54834/
% argument #1: any options
\newenvironment{customlegend}[1][]{%
    \begingroup
    % inits/clears the lists (which might be populated from previous
    % axes):
    \csname pgfplots@init@cleared@structures\endcsname
    \pgfplotsset{#1}%
}{%
    % draws the legend:
    \csname pgfplots@createlegend\endcsname
    \endgroup
}%
% makes \addlegendimage available (typically only available within an
% axis environment):
\def\addlegendimage{\csname pgfplots@addlegendimage\endcsname}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{customlegend}
    [
      legend style={%
        row sep = 5pt,
        /tikz/row 2/.style={yshift = 15pt},
      },
      legend entries={$a$,$e^x$,C,$d$},
    ]
    \addlegendimage{red,fill=black!50!red,area legend}
    \addlegendimage{red,fill=black!50!red,sharp plot}
    \addlegendimage{red,fill=black!50!red,mark=*,sharp plot}
    \addlegendimage{red,fill=black!50!red,ybar,ybar legend}
    \end{customlegend}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: shifted cells in a row]

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK changing `row sep` for a single row does not work for a normal TikZ `matrix`. In such a normal matrix you have to use the optional argument of `\\` at the end of the row to increase or decrease the `row sep`.

To enlarge the `row sep` you can insert an emty line in the legend:

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\newenvironment{customlegend}[1][]{%
    \begingroup
    \csname pgfplots@init@cleared@structures\endcsname
    \pgfplotsset{#1}%
}{%
    \csname pgfplots@createlegend\endcsname
    \endgroup
}%
\def\addlegendimage{\csname pgfplots@addlegendimage\endcsname}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{customlegend}[legend style={row sep = 5pt,
        %nodes=draw
    },
    legend entries={$a$,$e^x$,{[inner sep=0pt]},C,$d$}]
    \addlegendimage{red,fill=black!50!red,area legend}
    \addlegendimage{red,fill=black!50!red,sharp plot}
    \addlegendimage{empty legend}
    \addlegendimage{red,fill=black!50!red,mark=*,sharp plot}
    \addlegendimage{red,fill=black!50!red,ybar,ybar legend}
    \end{customlegend}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or you can insert an invisible node with an invisible row in the cell of the legend entry:

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\newenvironment{customlegend}[1][]{%
    \begingroup
    \csname pgfplots@init@cleared@structures\endcsname
    \pgfplotsset{#1}%
}{%
    \csname pgfplots@createlegend\endcsname
    \endgroup
}%
\def\addlegendimage{\csname pgfplots@addlegendimage\endcsname}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{customlegend}[legend style={row sep = 5pt,
        row 2 column 2/.style={
            execute at end cell={
                \node[anchor=north,yshift=-\dp\strutbox,inner sep=0pt,draw=none,fill=none]{\rule{0pt}{5pt}};
        }},
        %nodes=draw
    },
    legend entries={$a$,$e^x$,C,$d$}]
    \addlegendimage{red,fill=black!50!red,area legend}
    \addlegendimage{red,fill=black!50!red,sharp plot}
    \addlegendimage{red,fill=black!50!red,mark=*,sharp plot}
    \addlegendimage{red,fill=black!50!red,ybar,ybar legend}
    \end{customlegend}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Thanks. I've accepted the other answer because it's the simplest IMO, but I like these ideas!