# Add an entry in legend

Tags: tikz-pgf

In my case, the value in 'data.dat' is all `nan`.

```
\addplot table [
        x=X,
        y=value
    ] {data.dat};
    \addlegendentry{{\scriptsize small city}}
```

So in the legend, there is no entry for this table. But I still want to generate one. How should I customize it? Thanks!

Comment: You could use the \addlegendimage macro from the accepted answer in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54794/using-a-pgfplots-style-legend-in-a-plain-old-tikzpicture