# multicolumn in tikz legend

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend

I have a simple task, which I couldn't find a solution for so far.
I have a plot with 3 legend entries, 2 short ones, and a long one. I can use `legend columns=2,` to get a two-column legend but it looks like this:

aaaa ________________ bbbb

ccccccccccccccccccccc

What I like to have is:

aaaa ________ bbbb

ccccccccccccccccccccccccc

(I put the "_" for white space )

So, something like a multicolumn for a table used in a legend.
Do you have any idea how to do that?

Thanks, Axel

**Added at 12.04.21:**

Sorry for not adding the mentioned minimal example: I prepared it as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations, shapes, calc, backgrounds, shadings, arrows.meta, trees, positioning}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[%
        width=.7\textwidth,
        scale only axis,
        clip = false,
        legend columns=2,
        legend style={  at={(axis cs:1.5,1.2)},
            /tikz/column 2/.style={
                column sep=5pt},
            anchor=south}, 
        ]
        \addlegendimage{area legend,fill=red, opacity = 0.5}
        \addlegendimage{area legend,fill=gray, opacity = 0.5}
        \addlegendimage{area legend,fill=green, opacity = 0.5}
    
        \addplot[area legend, draw=black, fill=gray, fill opacity=0.5, forget plot]
        table[row sep=crcr] {%
        x   y\\
        1 0\\
        2 0\\
        2 1\\
        1 1\\
        }--cycle;
        \node[align=center]
        at (axis cs:1.5,0.5) {a};
        
        \addplot[area legend, draw=black, fill=red, fill opacity=0.5, forget plot]
        table[row sep=crcr] {%
        x   y\\
        0 0\\
        1 0\\
        1 1\\
        0 1\\
        }--cycle;
        \node[align=center]
        at (axis cs:0.5,0.5) {b};
        \addplot[area legend, draw=black, fill=green, fill opacity=0.5, forget plot]
        table[row sep=crcr] {%
        x   y\\
        2 0\\
        3 0\\
        3 1\\
        2 1\\
        }--cycle;
        \node[align=center]
        at (axis cs:2.5,0.5) {c};
        \legend{short text 1, short text 2, looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooog text};  
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome. Can you provide an example, where you show us your code of the things you tried so far?

Comment: If you have defined the `legendentries` this answer (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/488793/pgfplots-legend-with-multiple-columns-and-rows-different-entry-widths?rq=1) could be helpful.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look at your example and in cases like this I personaly build my own legend with the `matrix` option in `\usetikzlibrary`.
As mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/488793/pgfplots-legend-with-multiple-columns-and-rows-different-entry-widths?noredirect=1&lq=1) for long entries you can use `nodes={text width=width("the longest legend entry")}` to set the width of the node (in this case the legend). For the space between entry 1 and 2, I added `\hspace{length}`, which you can modify for your needs.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix} % <- added for self made legend

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[%
            name=plot,
            width=.7\textwidth,
            scale only axis,
            clip = false,
            legend columns=2,
            legend style={  at={(axis cs:1.5,1.2)},
                /tikz/column 2/.style={
                    column sep=5pt},
                anchor=south}, 
            ]
                                
            \addplot[area legend, draw=black, fill=gray, fill opacity=0.5, forget plot]
            table[row sep=crcr] {%
                x   y\\
                1 0\\
                2 0\\
                2 1\\
                1 1\\
            }--cycle;
            \node[align=center]
            at (axis cs:1.5,0.5) {a};
            
            \label{plot:a}
            
            \addplot[area legend, draw=black, fill=red, fill opacity=0.5, forget plot]
            table[row sep=crcr] {%
                x   y\\
                0 0\\
                1 0\\
                1 1\\
                0 1\\
            }--cycle;
            \node[align=center]
            at (axis cs:0.5,0.5) {b};
            
            \label{plot:b}
            
            \addplot[area legend, draw=black, fill=green, fill opacity=0.5, forget plot]
            table[row sep=crcr] {%
                x   y\\
                2 0\\
                3 0\\
                3 1\\
                2 1\\
            }--cycle;
            \node[align=center]
            at (axis cs:2.5,0.5) {c};
            
            \label{plot:c}
        
        \coordinate (legend) at (axis cs:1.5,1.2);
        
        \end{axis}
        
        \matrix[
        draw,
        matrix of nodes,
        anchor=south,
        font=\footnotesize,
        nodes={text width=width("looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooog text")},
        ] at (legend) {
            \ref{plot:a} short text 1 \hspace{1cm} \ref{plot:b}  short text 2 \\
            \ref{plot:c} looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooog text \\
        };

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```