# Why does a nan-only plot lead to an error when requesting a legend

Tags: pgfplots, legend, matlab2tikz

Let me first admit that this may be a really dumb question.

I am using `matlab2tikz` to export some figures from `matlab`. 
As I need some legend entries to be unrelated to my actual plots, I use nan-valued plots to create a legend without actually showing any plot.

In matlab, it seems like a *not so bad* idea. However, when these plots are passed to `pgfplots`, the compilation fails. 
If no legend is requested, everything works fine and the plots are discarded, but when trying to get a legend either with `legend entries={}` or `\addlegendentry{}` it fails.

I totally understand that if a plot contains `nan` these points are discarded or jumped based on the `unbounded coords` key, but why should the compilation fail in this case ?

Side note : I know that the `\addlegendimage{}` would probably be the best approach here (as proposed in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54834/141947), but that would not directly work as the `tex` file is built through `matlab2tikz`

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
            width=4cm,
            height=4cm,
            scale only axis,
            xmin=0,
            xmax=6,
            ymin=-1,
            ymax=1,
            axis x line=bottom,
            axis y line=left,
            legend entries={First,Second}
        ]
        % Works like a charm
        %\addplot [color=black, mark=o, mark options={solid, black}]  coordinates {(0,0) (1,0)};
        %\addplot [color=black, mark=+, mark options={solid, black}]  coordinates {(0,0) (1,0)};
        % Totally fails
        \addplot [color=black, mark=o, mark options={solid, black}]  coordinates {(nan,nan) (nan,nan)};
        \addplot [color=black, mark=+, mark options={solid, black}]  coordinates {(nan,nan) (nan,nan)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

*Remark*

Testing other solutions showed that using an

```
\addlegendimage{<\addplot options>}
\addlegenentry{<legend entry>}
```

pair after each `\addplot` leads to a correct compilation

Comment: How about just plotting them outside the plot range such that they get clipped away: `\addplot [color=black, mark=o, mark options={solid, black}]  
  coordinates {(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}-1,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}-1) 
  (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}-2,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}-2)};
        \addplot [color=black, mark=+, mark options={solid, black}]  coordinates 
  {(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}-1,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}-1) 
  (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}-2,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}-2)};`?

Comment: That's another possibility indeed, but it felt cleaner to use `nan`...

Comment: Well, `nan` makes the plot jump over the coordinates, so you have empty plots. In a way this is what you want but it also means that in your application there is no plot and thus no legend.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat AFAIK, using (even only) `nan` allows to create graphic objects with all their properties, wihout display. Let's put it this way, I actually need these plots, but the only part I'm interested in is their legend. In the answer you proposed, it's about the same thing, there is no point in plotting something that is out of plot range, `nan` is just the *ultimate* out-of-plot range ^^

Comment: I'm not an expert but this is definitely not how I interpret e.g. the example on p. 122 of the manual. My interpretation was always that `nan`s get skipped over. (As for your remark, this is not too surprising IMHO, you could then just leave the empty plots out and it will still work if you add `\addlegendimage{...}` and `\addlegenentry{<legend entry>}`.)

Comment: I totally agree to [Schrödinger's cat's first comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/194703/schr%c3%b6dingers-cat). The simplest attempt is to plot outside the visible are. But it it can be simplified a bit because you need only *one* coordinate and additionally either x *or* y needs to be outside the visible are. Thus `\addplot [...] coordinates {(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}-1,0};` is totally sufficient.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, my previous comment was not limited to `pgfplots`, but maybe the standard behaviour is different here. Regarding the remark, it is not surprising at all indeed, just a remark.

Comment: @StefanPinnow, I also agree, this would be the simplest answer, in order to avoid the compilation error. But I still have cannot figure why an *empty* `\addplot` (understand by that of which all coordinates have been filtered away) should totally be forgotten without e.g adding a `forget plot`

Comment: Christian hasn't commented here, so @-pinging him won't work. I think I would also expect that nan-only plots create proper legend entries (`matplotlib` and Octave are examples of systems where this happens), so a feature request on SourceForge is an option.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I added a feature request on the `pgfplots` tracker