# Pgfplots and Groupplot: Legend Management

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable, legend

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgf,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}


\begin{filecontents*}{data1.dat}
   t1       a1              t2       a2               t3        a3 
0.142    1.000           0.154    1.000            0.139     0.995
0.284    1.000           0.308    1.000            0.279     0.990
0.426    1.000           0.461    1.000            0.418     0.989
0.569    1.000           0.615    1.000            0.558     0.989
0.711    1.000           0.769    1.000            0.697     0.989
0.853    1.000           0.923    1.000            0.836     0.989
0.995    1.000           1.077    1.000            0.976     0.989
1.137    1.000           1.230    1.000            1.115     0.989
1.279    1.000           1.384    1.000            1.255     0.989
1.422    0.995           1.538    1.000            1.394     0.986
1.564    0.990           1.692    1.000            1.534     0.981  
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{data2.dat}
   t1       a1              t4       a4               t3        a3
3.554    0.920           3.845    0.950            3.485     0.913
3.696    0.915           3.999    0.945            3.625     0.908
3.838    0.910           4.153    0.939            3.764     0.903
3.980    0.905           4.306    0.934            3.904     0.898
4.123    0.900           4.460    0.929            4.043     0.893
4.265    0.895           4.614    0.923            4.182     0.888
4.407    0.890           4.768    0.918            4.322     0.883
4.549    0.885           4.922    0.912            4.461     0.878
4.691    0.880           5.075    0.907            4.601     0.873
4.833    0.875           5.229    0.902            4.740     0.868
4.976    0.870           5.383    0.896            4.880     0.864
5.118    0.865           5.537    0.891            5.019     0.859
5.260    0.860           5.691    0.885            5.158     0.854    
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
\begin{groupplot}[group style={
    group name=rzrxcomp,
    group size=1 by 2,
    xlabels at=edge bottom,
    ylabels at=edge left,
    vertical sep=4em
    },
    xmin = 0, xmax = 2,
    ymin = 0.8, ymax = 1,
    xtick distance = 0.2,
    ytick distance = 0.2,
    xlabel={$time\;[s]$},
    ylabel={$mass$},
    grid = both,
    grid style = {dotted},
    minor tick num = 1,
    major grid style = {lightgray!75},
    minor grid style = {lightgray!75},
    width = 0.85\textwidth,
    height = 0.50\textwidth,
    %scale only axis,
    %legend cell align = {left},
    %legend pos = north east
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.3)},
    anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    legend cell align = {left},
]
    
 \nextgroupplot

\addplot[smooth, black, very thick] table [x = {t1}, y = {a1}] {data1.dat};
\addplot[smooth, Lavender, very thick] table [x = {t2}, y = {a2}] {data1.dat};
\addplot[smooth, Violet, very thick] table [x = {t3}, y = {a3}] {data1.dat};

\nextgroupplot[legend entries={n1,n2,n3,n4}]



\addlegendimage{black, very thick, no markers}
\addlegendimage{Lavender, very thick, no markers}
\addlegendimage{Violet, very thick, no markers}
\addlegendimage{BurntOrange, dotted, very thick, no markers}

 
\addplot[smooth, black, very thick] table [x = {t1}, y = {a1}] {data2.dat};
\addplot[smooth, BurntOrange, dotted, very thick] table [x = {t4}, y = {a4}] {data2.dat};
\addplot[smooth, Violet, very thick] table [x = {t3}, y = {a3}] {data2.dat};
  

    %\legend{
    %n1,
    %n2,
    %n3,  
    %}
    
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Now imagine that we consider: `(t1,a1)=n1, (t2,a2)=n2, (t3,a3)=n3, (t4,a4)=n4`.
Is there a way to add the second column-set of values in `data2.dat`, i.e. `(t4, a4)`, as *n4* inside the legend? The issue is that I don't know how to add inside the legend *n4* without messing up with *n2*, which is in the same position of *n4* but in the first `\groupplot`. I need to keep one single legend, highlighting the four different plots with the related different colors.

**UPDATE**

Following @TorbjornT suggestion, I've used the `\addlegendimage` command in order to deal with plots' order and names in one single legend, and it works fine. The MWE has been updated with the new part. Now I have another question, how can I make solid `tick, very tick...` lines inside the generated legend? The `\addlegendimage` command doesn't seem to recognize or accept those style features.

Comment: Hi @TorbjornT, maybe you can give me a hand, I'd really appreciate.

Comment: You can either enter $(t_1,a_1)=a_1$ in a single column, or create a legend with a tabular (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54794/using-a-pgfplots-style-legend-in-a-plain-old-tikzpicture and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/602171/pgfplots-how-do-i-add-a-legend-to-a-plot-drawn-manually-not-using-addplot).

Comment: You can only @-ping users who have either edited the post or posted a comment previously, I only saw your comment now by accident. Too late to write an answer, but you can probably use `\addlegendimage` here. (Finally, please test your example :) You forgot to close the `figure`, `groupplot` and `tikzpicture` environment, and without `dvipsnames` the `Lavender` colour is undefined.)

Comment: You really only need one `\addlegendimage`, for the plot that is missing from that axis. I don't understand what you mean by the new question though, ticks have nothing to do with legends.

Comment: With `\legend{n1,n2,n3}` I was able to inherit all the features of the related plots, so for example, if n1 plot was built with a solid ultra thick line, the same thickness was reported into the legend. If I use `\addlegendimage` I can set the color, but the thickness is not eligible, and the command set just a standard value. So the final result is lacking in graphical correlation @TorbjørnT.

Comment: Are you sure? Changing the thickness works fine here.

Comment: You're right @TorbjørnT., I don't know why the code initally reported an error, a sort of warning that expressions like "very thick" were not allowed. I've tried again, and now it works... Likely the error was related to another one that meanwhile I've corrected.