# use plot markers such as '+',... in a table

Tags: tables

I have a lot of figures with a couple of legend entries in each of them. To this end, I am going to create a table where I list all line styles and the associated markers.
It is not difficult to create a straight or dashed line (line style) in my table, however, I do not know how to create markers, for instance a filled circle or an empty circle. Of course, one could create tikz pictures for that, but for me it seems that there are much easier approaches.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Actually, a tikzpicture in a savebox is an efficient solution.  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54794/using-a-pgfplots-style-legend-in-a-plain-old-tikzpicture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want something from TikZ, then use TikZ!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary[plotmarks]
\begin{document}
This is a plotmark: \tikz{\pgfuseplotmark{*}} \qquad -and another: \tikz{\pgfuseplotmark{diamond}}
\end{document}
```

[image: Text with two different plotmarks]

Comment: Obviously, one could find a matching symbol. -but I find that untenable.

Comment: Thank you (+1)! :-) For me, it worked also without \tikz{..}. Why did you use it in this context?

Comment: I thought that PGF could only be used inside TikZ. I do not know why it works without, but it messes with the alignment.