# Multiple text alignments in TikZ legend entries

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, horizontal-alignment, alignment, legend

I am looking for a simple way to have multiple alignments in a TikZ legend.

I have the following code which produces a TikZ figure:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=4in,height=3in,at={(0in,0in)},
scale only axis,
xmin=0,xmax=10,ymin=0,ymax=5,
legend style={legend cell align=left,align=left},
]
\addplot [color=red]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0   5\\
10   0\\
};
\addlegendentry{First: 1};
\addplot [color=blue]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0   4\\
10   1\\
};
\addlegendentry{Second: 2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The figure looks like this:

[image]

This is fine except that the numbers in the legend should be aligned. So what I want to have is this:

[image]

How can I achieve such alignment within the TikZ legend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy solution is to pick or compute a width and use `\makebox` or `\hbox to` to create each legend entry.

You can also create your own legend using a tabular.  See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54794/using-a-pgfplots-style-legend-in-a-plain-old-tikzpicture/148855?r=SearchResults&s=7%7C32.2902#148855)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\newlength{\tempdima}
\begin{document}
%\begin{figure}
\settowidth{\tempdima}{Second:\quad 2}% longest entry
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=4in,height=3in,at={(0in,0in)},
scale only axis,
xmin=0,xmax=10,ymin=0,ymax=5,
legend style={legend cell align=left,align=left},
]
\addplot [color=red]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0   5\\
10   0\\
};
\addlegendentry{\hbox to \tempdima {First:\hfill 1}};
\addplot [color=blue]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0   4\\
10   1\\
};
\addlegendentry{\makebox[\tempdima]{Second:\hfill 2}};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%\end{figure}
\end{document}
```