# Place the text of a legend entry underneath the corresponding line in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, legend

I have the following code, which brings me to the figure in the first image.

Now I would like to place the text (in this example: exp(x) and x²+2x+1) of the legend entries underneath the red and blue lines (like in the second Image) and not next to the lines.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            ymajorgrids,
            xmin = 0, xmax = 8,
            ymin = 0, ymax = 100,
            legend style = {at = {(0.15,-0.2)}, anchor = west, draw = none},
            legend columns = 2,
            ]
            
            \addplot[color=red]{exp(x)};
            \addlegendentry{exp(x)}
            \addplot [domain=-10:10, samples=100, color=blue] {x^2 + 2*x + 1};
            \addlegendentry{\(x^2 + 2x + 1\)}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Is there a simple way to achieve that?

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54794/using-a-pgfplots-style-legend-in-a-plain-old-tikzpicture  While the legend is implemented as a tabular, the side-by-side positioning is hard wired.